# Do I need to EQ frequencies before layering or after?

Tags: drums, mixing, ableton-live, frequency, samples

I want to create kick-samples, snare-samples, etc... by layering recorded samples (e.g. 909-Bass-Drum + click + crunch). Also I want to cutoff frequencies to get suitable samples for the mix. I use the EQ-Eight in Ableton to do this, but this is not relevant for my question.

**My Question:**

Do I need to layer and merge the raw samples into a single sample first before I cut the frequencies away?

[image]

Or do I need to cut off the frequencies of each sample before I merge them into a single sample?

[image]

Comment: Is the signal path on the 2nd image correct? Are you only going to be EQing the lows on sample 1, mids on 2 etc? The difference is significant.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I have updated the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each of those EQ diagrams is a band-pass filter, eliminating the frequencies outside the permitted band, then to EQ all after you comp the sample will affect the entire combination sample, so you will be allowing a little of the mid & high through from the low sample, & the same for the other two.

If you apply your EQ individually to each before you comp, then you will effectively eliminate all frequencies above 150Hz [allowing for your slope but no matter] from the low, everything outside 120Hz to 1kHz from the 2nd sample & so on.

Neither of these methods is right or wrong, but the sonic result will be different.
Your ears will have to tell you which they prefer.